# How to join Air Force Reserve with minor injuries that would interfere with Basic Training?

Tags: military, usa, us-air-force

Is it possible to get waivers on fitness part of the Basic Training for joining to Air Force Reserve? If not, is there a way to join Air Force Reserves without Basic Training?

Are there alternative paths that would skip Basic Training, for example: Civil Air Patrol (CAP) allows senior members and does not have fitness requirements as I know it, is there any way to transition to Air Force from there?

This does not need to just focus on flying. Although the pilot in question is already a commercial pilot, and has first class medical, just has some injuries to prevent extreme sports activities. (Like running 1.5 miles in 12 mins) So being able to fly would be very desirable (while not necessary).

Comment: Which fitness requirements exactly? Pilots are highly coveted positions, most are taken through military academies or ROTC programs. There is no transition from CAP to pilot program, and almost no waivers are allowed (I speak from great experience).

Comment: CAP and the military are two different things. CAP, Eagle Scouts, and ROTC might give you a leg up on being promoted from a private upon enlistment. But, it’s not going to give you much of an advantage past that.  If you want to be a pilot in the military, you have 2 routes. Either get a degree and become an officer. Or, join as enlisted in any capacity. Then, earn the opportunity (after a few years) to apply to warrant officer training for a rotary wing component. Either way, get your PT squared away now.

Comment: If you have a physical or mental issue that might keep you out of the military, your other option is to go to a flight school or collegiate flight program. Earning your flight certificate will give you a little credit toward OCS or WOCS. If not, at least you can be a civilian pilot. If you can not at least get a third class medical certificate on the civilian side, kiss your military flight dreams goodbye.

Comment: I updated the question. Question is not about how to become a pilot but more about how to join Air Force Reserves and serve (in any position) without fitness requirements. (Although being pilot would be great too)

Comment: Willingness to grant waivers depends entirely on the needs of the service, and this varies depending on factors like budget, retention, etc.  Only a recruiter will have the latest information.  Talk to the USAF, not random internet keyboard jockeys like us.

Comment: The Air Force used to grant waivers for the PT test if you could pass an alternate event. For instance, a timed bike ride instead of running to test your cardiovascular health. These waivers were usually granted to members already in the AF branch. Members going through basic training were still required to pass the regular PT test. The AF branch consists of Active, Reserve, and Air National Guard. All of which require their members to go through the same basic training together. CAP is an auxiliary of the AF. It is not technically in the AF branch. There is no easy route to AF through them.

Comment: @Dean F. - Yes, excellent point.  Waivers are generally for those who have paid their dues and the service has invested time and training in, and are later injured or have some condition that presents a challenge.  Why would they waiver an unproven person if they have a pool of qualified applicants to choose from?  Sucks for your friend, but life isn't fair.

Comment: The aviation medical requirements are strict. Flying a combat plane is physically demanding on it's own but imagine a scenario of ejecting over the ocean or in a wilderness area and having to survive. Couple this with the fact they choose the aircraft you fly, not you. That means you cant hide in a cargo plane if that isn't where they want you. Even if you don't want to be a pilot, the physical side of basics is designed to test you mental toughness and teamwork under pressure. You don't just get waivers for that because they need to assess if you have what it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to be an expert in some particular field that the military thinks it has a critical need for, you are more likely to get a waiver.  I've seen this happen with certain doctors who were specialists that the military had a critical shortage of for whatever reason.  These were not people just out of med school though.  They were senior specialists who needed waivers for age at the very least.  I'm not sure such a situation would ever occur for a pilot though since there are plenty of pilots out there who figure that they could "fly the box the plane came in", regardless of the type of plane.

Comment: Good point, Grumpy. I have seen the military give entry waivers to high level, uniquely skilled experts in a much needed field. In recent times, the military has been going the civilian consultant or contractor route to fill these positions. This keeps the individual out of the military leadership career tract. I’ve seen this with doctors, cyber security, & drone pilots. More often, I see waivers for higher ranking enlisted & officers (E-8, O-5 & above) regardless of their specialty. I would not count on any waivers below E-5 unless you have a mid to high six figure civilian salary specialty.